# Apache HTTPClient no such method ContentType.create

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

The stacktrace im getting is this.

```
[04:18:36 WARN]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:219)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.getEntity(MultipartEntity.java:119)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.isChunked(MultipartEntity.java:138)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:105)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:131)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:193)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
[04:18:36 WARN]:        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
```

The line this gets triggered at is this.

```
response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks to me like you're either missing a library or that there's a wrong version of a library on your classpath. I suspect httpcore and/or httpmime libraries.